# Set date and desired time in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to set date and time in my android app. The date should be today's date but the time should be set to 6:00 AM by default in the text field. I have read many links but most of them shows today's time and date (example: 2016-03-28 11:53:55).

```
 String timetxt1 = "06:00:00";
 Date datetxt1 = null;;
 try {
     datetxt1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(timetxt1);
 } catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 Calendar selectedDate1 = Calendar.getInstance();
 selectedDate1.setTime(datetxt1);

 edittxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(selectedDate1.getTime()));
```

Comment: post your code....what you have tried so far

Comment: Do you mean for a DatePicker / TimePicker? Which text field?

Comment: i just need to set date and time in the edit text. Date picker or time picker is not needed

Comment: User shows he did no effort to do some research. A simple google search could have solve the problem. Someone should vote the question down.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
 Date date = new Date();
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTime(date);
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);// for 6 hour
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);// for 0 min
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);// for 0 sec
 System.out.println(calendar.getTime());// print 'Mon Mar 28 06:00:00 ALMT 2016'
```

Comment: @Dyo Welcome ... Good to know It helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

This was useful to me.

```
fun getFormattedDateTime(dateString: String):String{
    var formattedDate=""
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.time = dateFormat.parse(dateString)!!
    calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY]=6
    calendar[Calendar.MINUTE]=0
    calendar[Calendar.SECOND]=0
    formattedDate=sdf.format(calendar.time)
    return formattedDate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get current date use below method

```
 public static String getCurrentDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

This will give you the current date alone. And if you want the time to be 6:00AM use the below method

```
  public static String getCurrentDateAndTime6() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    return dateFormat.format(calendar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done like this,

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setHours(6);
    date.setMinutes(0);
    date.setSeconds(0);
    Log.d("DateTime", dateFormat.format(date));
```

**OUTPUT :**  `2016/03/28 06:00:00`

Comment: The set methods are deprecated as of API 16